power on-off, scan on-off, discoverable on-off, pair device, unpair device, list devices powershell commands not working in windows
power on-off, scan on-off, discoverable on-off, pair device, unpair device, list devices powershell commands not working in windows

const { exec } = require('child_process');

/**
 * Function to execute a command
 * Helper function to run a PowerShell command
 *
 * @param {*} command
 * @param {*} callback
 */
function executeCommand(command, callback) {
  // `runas /user:Administrator "powershell -Command \\"${command}\\""`
  // `"${command}"`
  exec(`${command}`, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`Error executing PowerShell command: ${error.message}`);
      return;
    }
    if (stderr) {
      console.error(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
      return;
    }
    console.log(error, stdout.trim(), stderr)
    callback(error, stdout.trim(), stderr);
  });
}


/**
 * Enable Bluetooth
 *
 */
function turnOn(callback) {
  const command = `powershell -Command "Start-Service bthserv"`;
  executeCommand(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log('Bluetooth enabled');
    callback(stdout);
  });
}


/**
 * Disable Bluetooth
 *
 */
function turnOff(callback) {
  const command = `powershell -Command "Stop-Service bthserv"`;
  executeCommand(command, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    console.log('Bluetooth disabled');
    callback(stdout);
  });
}


/**
 * Start Scanning
 *
 * @param {*} callback
 */
function scanOn(callback) {
  const command = 'powershell -Command "Start-BluetoothScan"';
  executeCommand(command, callback);
}


/**
 * Stop Scanning
 *
 * @param {*} callback
 */
function scanOff(callback) {
  const command = 'powershell -Command "Stop-BluetoothScan"';
  executeCommand(command, callback);
}


/**
 * Make Pairable On
 *
 * @param {*} callback
 */
function pairableOn(callback) {
  const command = 'powershell -Command "Set-BluetoothPairable -On"';
  executeCommand(command, callback);
}


/**
 * Make Pairable Off
 *
 * @param {*} callback
 */
function pairableOff(callback) {
  const command = `powershell -Command "Set-BluetoothPairable -Off"`;
  executeCommand(command, callback);
}


the errors that i get are follows:

// // // Example usage
// agentOn((result) => console.log('Agent turned on:', result));
// agentOff((result) => console.log('Agent turned off:', result));
// scanOn((result) => console.log('Scanning started:', result));
// scanOff((result) => console.log('Scanning stopped:', result));
// powerOn((result) => console.log('Power started:', result));
// powerOff((result) => console.log('Power stopped:', result));

Error executing PowerShell command: Command failed: powershell -Command "Set-BluetoothPairable -Off"
Set-BluetoothPairable : The term 'Set-BluetoothPairable' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check 
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-BluetoothPairable -Off
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-BluetoothPairable:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 

Error executing PowerShell command: Command failed: powershell -Command "Stop-BluetoothScan"
Stop-BluetoothScan : The term 'Stop-BluetoothScan' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the 
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Stop-BluetoothScan
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Stop-BluetoothScan:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
 

Error executing PowerShell command: Command failed: powershell -Command "Start-BluetoothScan"
Start-BluetoothScan : The term 'Start-BluetoothScan' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the     
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Start-BluetoothScan
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Start-BluetoothScan:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


Error executing PowerShell command: Command failed: powershell -Command "Disable-BluetoothDevice -Agent"
Disable-BluetoothDevice : The term 'Disable-BluetoothDevice' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.       
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Disable-BluetoothDevice -Agent
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Disable-BluetoothDevice:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


Error executing PowerShell command: Command failed: powershell -Command "Enable-BluetoothDevice -Agent"
Enable-BluetoothDevice : The term 'Enable-BluetoothDevice' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check   
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-BluetoothDevice -Agent
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Enable-BluetoothDevice:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


Error executing PowerShell command: Command failed: powershell -Command "Set-BluetoothPairable -On"
Set-BluetoothPairable : The term 'Set-BluetoothPairable' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check     
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-BluetoothPairable -On
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Set-BluetoothPairable:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


Are the commands working if you type them in the powershell directly?

looks like the bluetooth plugin is not installed - you should provide more details about your PowerShell environment

@Marc no commands are not working directly in powershell.

@Marc i have bluetooth command line tools. ex: BluetoothCommandLineTools/BtUnpair.exe. but the error persists . this command however works cmd /c "BluetoothCommandLineTools/BtUnpair.exe -a ${deviceId}"

The issue lies in the fact that standard PowerShell on Windows desktops does not have built-in cmdlets for directly controlling Bluetooth functions like power on/off, scanning, pairing, etc. These functionalities are typically handled through the Windows Settings app or dedicated Bluetooth management software.
Why Standard PowerShell Commands Don't Work
Limited Bluetooth Integration: PowerShell primarily focuses on system administration and script automation, with Bluetooth control being an area not extensively covered in its standard modules.
Windows Settings App: The Windows Settings app is the primary interface designed for managing Bluetooth devices and settings.
Third-Party Tools: Many specialized tools offer more comprehensive Bluetooth management capabilities beyond the basic functions provided by the Settings app.
I have face the same issue for this website: Istanbul Property

we should refrain from giving vague answers to a vague question in a chatGPT style - instead, ask OP to provide the details to clarify open issues so that answers can be spot on and helpful to future readers

i have bluetooth command line tools. ex: BluetoothCommandLineTools/BtUnpair.exe. but the error persists . this command however works cmd /c "BluetoothCommandLineTools/BtUnpair.exe -a ${deviceId}"
